# Какие основные черты языка (любого), те черты, которые создают "лицо" языка?

Tags: фонетика, лексика, морфология

Я так понимаю лексика, фонетика, морфология, что еще? Что больше влияет, лексика, как я понимаю, не вначале списка, первой должна быть фонетика, как мне кажется. Есть мысли?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, для какой цели это нужно, но лингвисты говорят, что у каждого человека в голове есть грамматика его родного языка — механизм, который помогает человеку говорить правильно. Под грамматикой любого языка понимается наука о правильном построении предложений, фраз, текстов.

Грамматика-это морфология + синтаксис. Кроме грамматики, учитываются семантика, лексикология и фонетика. Типология языков часто основывается на морфологии. Вот,например,классическая четырехтипная систематика на основе морфологии:

Корневые языки - изолирующие, для которых характерно полное отсутствие словоизменения и наличие грамматической значимости порядка слов, представленных только корнями.

Агглютинативные языки: Характеризуются развитой системой употребления суффиксов, приставок, добавляемых к неизменяемой основе слова, которые используются для выражения числа, падежа, рода и др.

Флективные языки

Профлективные (агглютинативно-флективные)

. Современная типология  опирается на данные  морфологии(а здесь и морфемика, и словообразование), синтаксиса,  фонологии и  семантики как части лексикологии( Ономасиология Семасиология  Фразеология  Ономастика  Лексикография Стилистика ).

Характеризуя язык, мы говорим и о его письменности, т.е. о графике, алфавите (кириллица, или латиница, или...)

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос о том, что в языке главнее,  уже некорректен. Т.к. каждый раздел языкознания по своему главный и составляет его неотъемлемую часть. Другое дело вопрос '' С чего надо начинать изучение языка''. Здесь, конечно, на первый план выходит фонетика, а потом уже морфология, орфография, синтаксис.

Comment: я не спрашивал, что главнее. 
Есть основные черты языка.
Взять, к примеру, лексику и фонетику. Если язык под влиянием соседнего языка заимствует много слов, как это влияет на язык? Становится ли он "другим" языком или какое в этом случае (соседство другого языка) будет влияние на фонетику или морфология и пр? Что должно изменится в языке, чтобы можно было про него сказать, я понимаю, что это звучит по-дилетантски, что это "другой" язык?

Answer (score 0):

Первой должна быть грамматика. Про глокую куздру слышали?

Comment: Но если мы говорим о языке, который не знаем и первый раз слышим, то грамматика грамматикой, но первое, что обращает на себя внимание, это фонетика - шипящий польский, хекающий украинский или грассирующий г во французском, как мне кажется, она больше других влияет на восприятие языка.